# Arrange items by post id, irrespective of a user's ID

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to build a system that retrieves posts from users that a logged-in user happens to "follow". The system works, however user posts do not get  arranged the way I would like. That is, they are arrange in clusters/sets depending on the user id that has been queried.

For example, if user one has three posts, his three posts will be grouped together; if user two has five posts, his five posts will be grouped together, irrespective of what that post's id is relative to posts other users have made.

I would like posts not to cluster together, but to display in order (of id or date) irrespective of the user that has made the post.

I am not sure if I have explained the problem well enough, but here is my server-side code [below].

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

```
PHP/MYSQL

public 
    function get_posts_of_followed() {
        include "connect.php";
        $userid = $this->getUserId();


        // Posts from users the loggedin user follows
        $postArray = array();


        // Get the user_ids of the people the loggedin user follows
        $followed = array();
            $get_followed_query = "SELECT `followed_id` FROM `user_follows` WHERE `follower_id` = '$userid'";
            $get_followed_result = mysqli_query($con, $get_followed_query);
                while($row_followed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_followed_result)){
                    $ids = array("followed_ids" => $row_followed['followed_id']);
                    array_push($followed, $ids);
                }

            foreach($followed as $theirid){

                // Get post_data from users the loggedin user follows
                $query_posts = "SELECT `id`,`post_title`,`user_id`, `post`, `date`, `category` 
                                 FROM `user_posts` 
                                 WHERE `user_id`= '". $theirid['followed_ids']."' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
                $post_result = mysqli_query($con, $query_posts);
                while($postData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($post_result)){

                    // Get profile_data from the users the loggedin user follows
                    $query_userData = "SELECT `id`,`firstname`, `lastname`, `profilepic` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '". $postData['user_id'] ."'";
                    $userData_result = mysqli_query($con, $query_userData);
                       while($userData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userData_result)){

                        $data = array("firstname" => $userData['firstname'], "lastname" => $userData['lastname'], "profilepic" => $userData['profilepic'], "post_title" =>  $postData['post_title'], "user_id" => $userid, "date" => $postData['date'], "post_id" => $postData['id'], "the_post" => $postData['post'],"category" => $postData['category']);
                        array_push($postArray, $data);
                       }   
                 }
             }
             return $postArray;

     }

}
```

Comment: So use `ORDER BY...` in your SQL queries? [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 'ORDER BY' doesn't fix the problem. The returned items still get clustered/grouped in sets related to the user id being queried.

Comment: I made an edit that includes 'ORDER BY `id` DESC'. Let me know if you have any suggestions. :)

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, the second query only ever looks at one user at a time so they're ordered correctly, but one user at a time. Two other options then, one is to use `usort()` to sort the data in PHP after you've generated the array, the other is to merge your queries into a single query using joins, which would be my suggested option.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will give both methods a go, and get back to you. Thanks for looking at my code.

Comment: Thinking about it, joins might be overkill, a simple subselect may do the trick. Not tested, but here's a possible example http://pastebin.com/rKHvMdxi

Comment: Jon, you're awesome! That neat little trick (sub-select) fixed the problem. I also have a new technique to use in the future. Thank you.